# Can not drag and drop in Spyder when run from cmd

Tags: python, cmd, conda, spyder

When running Spyder from the command promp, we can not drag and drop files in the IDE.

Using anaconda prompt as admin.

```
(dev) C:\somepath\somedir> spyder
```

```
(dev) C\somepath\somedir:> START /B spyder > $null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running any software as admin, you will loose the ability to drag and drop your files.

See: [Drag and Drop File into Application under run as administrator](https://superuser.com/questions/59051/drag-and-drop-file-into-application-under-run-as-administrator)